# Fetch API doesn't work with server_name in nginx

Tags: javascript, express, nginx, nginx-config

I have Nginx working on my computer that servers solid.js frontend and two express.js servers.
I'm trying to fetch an endpoint that is exposed in one of my express app.
Everything works correctly until I specify server_name in nginx config for my solid app.
The error that I get is net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

nginx config for the frontend app

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name home.localhost;

        location / {
            root D:/Programming/JavaScript/mocks/nginx-tests/solid-statis/dist;
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
    }
```

nginx config for my backend apps

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.localhost;

        location /first-api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7777/;
        }

        location /second-api/ {
            proxy_pass http://ocalhost:7778/;
        }
    }
```

my express configuration

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.get('/v1/greetings', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: 'Hallo' });
});

app.listen(7778, () => {
  console.log("I'm listening on 7778");
});
```

I tried to add all of this to my backend config for nginx

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

I also tried

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

Comment: The home.localhost domain is somehow resolved by the browser on the DNS level?

Comment: Well, ngnix maps it to my solid app so it's getting resolved (when I hit home.localhost on my browser I get my app). The problem is that within solid app, fetch(`http://api.localhost/second-api/v1/greetings`) works only if server_name key is not specified in my config.

Comment: Obviously, you were right and I was stupid. Apparently, I didn't know how Nginx and DNS work. (Additionally when my server_name home.localhost was resolved to localhost, no it completely threw home aside). I changed my hosts file to reflect my addresses and it fixed everything. Thank you for the idea :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question:

It turned out that *.localhost is interpreted as just localhost, and that threw me off completely. So when I changed it I understand that nginx didn't work as it should. Then I changed server_name and updated my hosts file to map it correctly and it started to work as it was supposed to :D